# SQL - selecting multiple tables so as to combine multiple tables

Tags: sqlite

I want to use `SELECT *` from multiple tables table1 and table2 to get the output table which is nothing but table2 data appended to table1. How do I construct the `SELECT * FROM` statement ?

**Table1**:

```
id  model  datetime     driver   distance
---|-----|------------|--------|---------
1  | S   | 04/03/2009 | john   | 399 
2  | X   | 04/03/2009 | juliet | 244
3  | 3   | 04/03/2009 | borat  | 555
```

**Table2**:

```
id  model  datetime     driver   distance
---|-----|------------|--------|---------
4  | 3   | 03/03/2009 | john   | 300
5  | X   | 03/03/2009 | juliet | 200
```

Desired output:

```
 model  datetime     driver   distance
 -----|------------|--------|---------
  S   | 04/03/2009 | john   | 399 
  X   | 04/03/2009 | juliet | 244
  3   | 04/03/2009 | borat  | 555
  3   | 03/03/2009 | john   | 300
  X   | 03/03/2009 | juliet | 200
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out this might help you

```
    SELECT table1.model, table1.datetime, table1.driver, table1.distance FROM table1
    UNION ALL SELECT table2.model, table2.datetime, table2.driver, table2.distance FROM table2;
```

Comment: The output should not contain `id`. And why UNION and not UNION ALL?

Comment: Now it's invalid SQL. And why UNION and not UNION ALL?

Comment: @CL.. UNION removes duplicate records, UNION ALL does not.

Comment: Why do you try to remove duplicates that don't exist? This just slows the query down by forcing the DB to create a temporary results table. And it's still invalid SQL.

Comment: @CL. Okay fine... Have Updated the answer

Answer (score -1):

union statement get slow for fetching the large data from the db, you can use join here,

```
select * from table0 left join table2 on table0.b = table2.b where table2.col is not null
```